# Why should I expect the product of sum of four squares to be a sum of four squares? How did Euler come up with it?

Tags: soft-question, intuition

Euler discovered the lovely identity shown here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity

Is there a natural reason to assume a solution can be found? Any intuition?

I saw that any symmetric bilinear form is diagonalizable, and so an intuition might be that if we get lucky when diagonalizing the basis won't contain complex numbers. However the product of 2 sums of 4 squares isn't a symmetric bilinear form, is there a more general diagonalizing statement that I'm not aware of to take care of those almost symmetric polynomials?

Comment: Not sure it helps, but from the [French Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identit%C3%A9_des_quatre_carr%C3%A9s_d%27Euler) there appears to be a nice connection to quaternions. The norm of their products equals the product of their norms.

Comment: Keith Conrad's Hurwitz notes ( http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/hurwitzlinear.pdf and http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/hurwitzrepnthy.pdf ) shine some light on this. The four-square identity comes from a certain orthogonal $4$-dimensional representation of a quaternion(?) group.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks, a tiny bit too advanced for me though :(

Comment: suggest the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity  which shows that Euler would have had some motivation to search for such an identity for four squares, after whatever experiments he may have done suggested that the product of two numbers, both the sum of four squares, would also be the sum of four squares. I would emphasize that Euler was brilliant and persistent, and was not deterred by the prospect of long calculations. Oh: if two numbers are the sum of ***three*** squares, their product may not be. For example, $3 \cdot 5 = 15$ is not three squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citing [this article](https://books.google.de/books?id=h4aBBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=brief%20euler%204.%20Mai%201748%20goldbach&source=bl&ots=A5n6PJ_voM&sig=QvjSHk135UAyzgfV1Q0YULevBTc&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT2tLD6rvLAhXBCpoKHRCVB7cQ6AEILTAE#v=onepage&q=brief%20euler%204.%20Mai%201748%20goldbach&f=false) by Winfried Scharlau from "E.A. Fellmann: Leonhard Euler 1707–1783: Beiträge zu Leben und Werk, Springer Verlag, 2013":

> Parallel to his hitherto told research Euler always occupied himself with Fermat's theorems on the representation of numbers as sums of squares or polygonial numbers. His correspondence with Goldbach at this time gives a lively picture of his many and never dwindling attempts about these theorems.
>   It must have been a close thought to him to try to apply the method of generating functions to Fermat's problems.

The letter to Goldbach, May 4th, 1748:  [Link](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/correspondence/letters/OO0841.pdf)

It starts at page 452 
("Folgendes *theorema* kann auch dienen in vielen Fällen die *quatuor quadrata* selbst zu bestimmen, woraus eine Zahl zusammen gesetzt ist")

> The following theorem can in many cases serve to determine the
>   *quatuor quadrata* of which a number is composed

(The language is German with a lot of Latin)

Another article by Herbert Pieper on Euler's attempts: [Link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086083710037)

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know an article in English? I can't find anything :(. Alternatively if you happen to find more information in German/Latin and you're willing to translate it I'd be very thankful!

I'm not marking your answer as accepted yet since I'm hoping to see if there is some intuition to the theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the article, very satisfying! Follow up (which is more of a history question), what was Euler's response to Lagrange's success in proving the theorem?